# Retrieve entries from table via pivot table Octobercms

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, octobercms

can anyone help me writing query to retrieve words from my words table in such way that words are having a belongsToMany relationship to Type model via types pivot table?

Here's how relationship looks like in Word.php

```
 public $belongsToMany = [
    'typeswb' => [
        'Yeoman\Wordbank\Models\Type',
        'table' => 'yeoman_wordbank_types_pivotb',
        'order' => 'typesofwordbank'
    ]
];
```

Here is how types table looks like

```
    mysql> select * from yeoman_wordbank_types;
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
| id | typesofwordbank    | slugoftypes        |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | Common Words       | common-words       |
|  2 | Common Expressions | common-expressions |
|  3 | Common Proverbs    | common-proverbs    |
|  4 | Common Idioms      | common-idioms      |
+----+--------------------+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and wheres how types pivot table looks like

```
mysql> select * from yeoman_wordbank_types_pivotb;
+---------+---------+
| word_id | type_id |
+---------+---------+
|      18 |       2 |
|       5 |       4 |
|       9 |       3 |
|      19 |       1 |
|      31 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see `type_id` are connected to `words_id`. where `types_id's` are from **types table** and `words_id's` are from **word table**.

I need to find a way to get the words using `types_id`.

I have tried following

```
// $query = Word::all();
// foreach ($query->typeswb as $typeswb) {
   // $queryy = $typeswb->pivot->type_id = 1;
// }
```

and some other combination like that but all in vain, strangely I get `Word::find(1)` null on this while `Word::all()` return an array of 6 items in the collection.

Thank you for reading, I will appreciate any hint or help very much.

Comment: Have you defined `$belongsToMany` on your `Types` model?

Comment: Hi @Meysam, as you can see in that start of question, i did!

Comment: No, what I can see is `$belongsToMany` in your `Word` model. I am asking about `Types` model.

Comment: @Meysam no i didn't define any inverse relation on `Types` model as i just wanted to have `belongToMany` relations of types on my `Word` model. Although, i have solved this see my answer :) cheers!

Comment: Well, I think you are reinventing the wheel in your answer. Defining the inverse relation on `Types` model will help you avoid that.

Comment: @Meysam is that so, i really didn't know if i was reinventing, so, how would you write that query if i had the belongToMany relation on `Types` Although, to me it seems really logical. All i'm doing is that telling `Types` you belongs to many `Words` and later i'm writing query about retrieving words depending upon the `types_id` key.

Comment: I think `Type::find(type_id)->words` should achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks but i am quite ok with my current query. this was one of my search engine functionality as i had to chain a lot of other constraints like checking language, checking types, check for publish/Draft words and query DB depending upon the letter being typed in input. In-short, My current answer was quite helpful in chain a lot of constraints in one line for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i solved this, normally via builder component, this functionality is very easy to achieve but was kinda of unclear how to do on my own in one of my own component. So, here's how i solved this:

```
$query = Word::whereHas('typeswb', function($q)
         {
             $q->where('type_id', '=', post('typesofwordsearch')); //post('typesofwordsearch') return integer which are id's of types according to the table
         })->limit(5)->get();
```

**Breakdown about how it is working:**

So, there could be another way but after trying long, this one worked.

Firstly i am using my Word model where in the word model, i have `typeswb` which is defining `belongToMany` relation (see question for that). I am using `whereHas` [read this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) for more info on that. Basically using `wherehas` i am instructing query to look up with relation. Afterwards, In function closure, I'm queries using one of key of my types table i.e `type_id`. For keys of types table again see my question above.

Hope that this will help someone. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide pivot table:

```
public $belongsToMany = [                                                                                                                                                                                      
        'typeswb' => [                                                                                                                                                                                                
        'Yeoman\Wordbank\Models\Type',                                                                                                                                                                      
        'table'=>'yeoman_wordbank_types_pivotb',                                                                                                                                                               
        'key' =>'word_id ',                                                                                                                                                                                         
        'otherKey' => 'type_id ',                                                                                                                                                                                   
        'pivot'    => ['word_id ', 'type_id '],                                                                                                                                                                      
        ],                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    ];
```

Comment: are you sure, you are addressing my question? i know i can provide the additional keys in case i want to use different key names in my pivot. but i ask about how to query.